# Laravel LDAP gives protected array every time

Tags: php, laravel-5, ldap

I have successfully integrated LDAP in LARAVEL 5 and when I am trying to fetch all users from LDAP Server by below statement. I am getting result by in protected array.

$user = Adldap::search()->get();

I have tried toArray() method. which is not working. Is there any way to get normal unprotected array?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

toJson() would work in this case.

$user = Adldap::search()->get()->toJson();

This will result in Json format and can be converted to array by

json_decode($user);